# Issues with CORS after connecting HTTP Functions to Firebase Hosting

Tags: reactjs, cors, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have a Cloud functions powered backend architecture which works with my React Native App. Now, am trying to build a React app dashboard so that I can visualize my application's resources and user behaviors. My approach remains the same, route all calls to the cloud functions endpoint `https://[region]-[project].cloudfunctions.net/[function_name]`.

The challenge is that I get a CORS blocking my request from the browser: This is understandable and the solution is to `set up a middleware to handle CORS` which has been done and works well.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import * as cors from 'cors';
const corsHandler = cors({origin: true});

const signUp = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  corsHandler(request, response, () => {;})

  .../ signUp logic below
})
```

Everything looks Ok, except that I don't want to stop the CORS check, i.e. I want to remove `corsHandler(request, response, () => {;})` but the same time I also don't want CORS blocking requests from Firebase hosting. After Googling, I discovered I can connect HTTP Functions to Firebase Hosting and use `rewrites` under the hosting rule to access cloud functions trigger endpoints.

```
rewrites under hosting rule in firebase.json
--------------------------------------------
"rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "/signUp",
        "function": "signUp"
      }
    ]
```

But this is also blocked by CORS. I have read the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites). I am using Fetch API with a config as shown below

```
 method: "GET", // POST
 mode: "cors", // no-cors, cors, *same-origin
 cache: "no-cache", // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
 credentials: "same-origin", // include, *same-origin, omit
 headers: {
     Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
     "Content-Type": "text/json;application/json;charset=UTF-8"
 },
 redirect: "follow", // manual, *follow, error
 referrer: "no-referrer", // no-referrer, *client
 timeout: 20000
```

Please any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Make sure that the function is not ending with error; I think, when that happens, the browser shows CORS issues.

Comment: Can you explain further please, @fractalix

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to limit the origin of requests coming into Cloud Functions.  If your function allows access to any outside IP address, it must allow access to all IP addresses.  The only way you have to control access is to require the client to provide some credentials which your function can check when it's invoked.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @dougstevenson. But my concern is more on why there's a CORS issue when the request is coming from firebase hosting after I have connected HTTP Functions to Firebase Hosting.

Comment: Ok, it was confusing to me when you said "My goal is to ensure that other endpoints that cannot have the required authorization headers are not accessible from domains outside my organization's." There's no limiting by domain. If you are instead wondering why cors is required when you think it should not, please edit the question to more clearly illustrate the issue showing both client and server code that doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: Hi @dougstevenson, I have edited the question and I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: I suggest also including the client JavaScript.

Comment: Ok I will do so ASAP, but can you help to suggest what is needful under this context from the client JS code? This is so I can provide the right elements to enable assistance on this. Meanwhile, I have added the fetch api config object to the question

Comment: I'm recommending showing all the code in case you're doing something wrong.  You never know.

Comment: Hi @dougstevenson, please find the code in the following sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-frost-54tq6?autoresize=1&fontsize=14. I hope this gives a better insight. Thanks so much

Comment: Hi @dougstevenson, did you check out the code sandbox?